# How to get facebook page's like list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to get liked users list from my page(which i am an administrator) using page access token? I have tried `{pageID}?fields=fan_count,country_page_likes` and returns only

```
{
  "fan_count": 123,
  "country_page_likes": 123,
  "id": "************"
}
```

Seems `insights` are not return any users list

Comment: No it is not possible. Why would you need it?

Comment: i just read the question that duplication and comment section all makes sense thank you anyway.

Comment: @WizKid so page admin cannot get even user app-scoped id right?

Comment: Correct. What would you need it for?

Comment: I was trying to test get user's app-scoped id through page @WizKid

Comment: What do you need app-scoped user ID for?

Comment: I was trying to check if user liked my post

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: i though i can check post likes and iterating through with it, seems i was wrong.

Comment: @WizKid is there any possible way to check that? because scrolling down through post reaction is kind of a huge mess

Comment: What is the final goal you are trying to solve?

Comment: my partners doing a giveaway. And when we selecting winner, winner must be in only for those people who have liked. @WizKid